# Can you have customer getter on a non-nullable property?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an easier way to do the following?

```
    val placeholder: Bitmap
        get() { if (_placeholder == null)
            _placeholder = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.resources, fancy_placeholder)
        /** do something else here **/
        return  _placeholder!! }
    private var _placeholder: Bitmap? = null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be a solution:

```
fun <G: Any> lazyGetter(init: ()->G, onGet: G.()->Unit): ReadOnlyProperty<Any?, G> =
    object : ReadOnlyProperty<Any?, G> {
        private var value: G? = null
        override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): G {
            if (value == null) value = init(); value!!.onGet(); return value!! } }
```

Which makes the above example like so:

```
    val placeholder: Bitmap by lazyGetter({
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.resources, fancy_placeholder) }) {
        /** do something else here **/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the lazy delegate for this purpose:

```
val placeholder: Bitmap by lazy { 
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.resources, fancy_placeholder) 
}
```

If you aren't worried about thread safety, this is lighter weight, but less brief:

```
val placeholder: Bitmap by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) { 
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(appContext.resources, fancy_placeholder) 
}
```

Comment: I edit my question just a bit. It is important to have a getter or to execute some code in another way upon accessing the variable.

Comment: In that case, there is no briefer way for you to do this than what you have. But of course if you use this pattern repeatedly, you could write your own delegate that makes it this brief. But I would consider a side effect from a getter to be an antipattern.